# How to mock an Amazon DynamoDB v3 in Nodejs using Jest?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using an Amazon DynamoDB package from aws-sdk v3 for javascript.
Here is the docs which I have followed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-examples.html
I have installed "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb" package to perform CRUD operations from code.

I have imported commands from package in this way:

```
import { DynamoDBClient, PutItemCommand, DeleteItemCommand, UpdateItemCommand, GetItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
const dynamodbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: process.env.DYNAMODB_REGION, endpoint: process.env.DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT });
const result = await dynamodbClient.send(new PutItemCommand(params));
```

I have tried to mock Amazon DynamoDB following Jest docs but it was calling real Amazon DynamoDB in local.

How to mock these "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb" package in Nodejs?  
Please provide an example in Nodejs!

Comment: if you are looking to write unit test cases for this,  You will need to build a wrapper over dynamoDb and mock that wrapper layer. one way to implement that wrapper layer is to build a Repository pattern. Mocking Dynamodb is not impossible but mocking your own wrapper layer would be far more easier.

Answer (score 2):

AWS [recommends](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/mocking-modular-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3-in-unit-tests/) mocking DynamoDB and the rest of AWS with [aws-sdk-client-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-client-mock) with [documentation](https://github.com/m-radzikowski/aws-sdk-client-mock#readme) included with the module.

Install aws-sdk-client-mock and probably aws-sdk-client-mock-jest

```
npm i aws-sdk-client-mock aws-sdk-client-mock-jest
```

Import the module

```
import {mockClient} from "aws-sdk-client-mock";
import 'aws-sdk-client-mock-jest';
```

Create a mock. Reset after each test

```
describe('Winner purge service', () => {
  const ddbMock = mockClient(DynamoDBClient)

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    ddbMock.reset()
  })
```

Define responses

```
    ddbMock
        .on(ScanCommand).resolvesOnce({
        Items: [marshall(configItem, {removeUndefinedValues: true})],
        Count: 1
    })
    ddbMock.on(QueryCommand)
        .resolvesOnce({
            Items: [marshall(olderWinner)], Count: 1
        })
        .resolves({
            Items: [], Count: 0
        })
```

Test calls

```
expect(ddbMock.commandCalls(DeleteItemCommand).length).toBe(0)
```

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: My issues comes with an error where it says resource not found when you do not add endpoint and region into it

Comment: Not mocking everything AWS?

Comment: could you elaborate?
i see the resource not found error only when my i use dynamodbclient in layers.
it works fine in lambda.
here is an example repo
https://github.com/hafizali05/apigw-lambda-dynamodb

Comment: added stackoverflow question if you fancy answering there

......................
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76354962/mocking-dynamodb-works-in-lambda-function-but-not-in-layer-with-aws-sdk-client-m

Comment: I'm getting also the resource, region issue, as if it wasn't really getting mocked

Answer (score 1):

This answer may come a bit late :)
Currently there are two very useful package to deal with aws dynamodb mocks

- [@shelf/jest-dynamodb](https://jestjs.io/docs/dynamodb)
- [jest-dynalite](https://github.com/freshollie/jest-dynalite) - works without java and `@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb`

I my case, I ended up using the second option, `jest-dynalite` since it doesnt require java and its very easy to configure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AWSMock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) along with sinon and mock the method and response as you want. It works really great with jest and it doesn't call a real database.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the aws dynamodb jar and use an endpoint with your dynamodb client.

You can setup a docker container to run dynamodb:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 instructure/dynamo-local-admin:latest
```

When you setup the dynamodb client for your tests, keep using the endpoint:

```js
import { DynamoDBClient, PutItemCommand, DeleteItemCommand, UpdateItemCommand, GetItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
const dynamodbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: process.env.DYNAMODB_REGION, endpoint: process.env.DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT });
const result = await dynamodbClient.send(new PutItemCommand(params));
```

After you run your tests, you can check the results on the admin UI available at `localhost:8000`.